# having trouble with doing math with text box value and a calculated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I am using a function in my code that takes and does math with a value from a text box that the user writes in and also a calculated value that is used earlier in the page. If the text box value is not a positive number an alert will appear showing that the value must be a positive number. If it is a positive number, it shows an alert with the outcome of the math. The only problem is, when this happens, what appears is where the number should be there is instead "NaN". I believe this is because the values I'm using aren't actually numbers but I'm not sure how to fix this.

```html
function computeTotalDistance(result) {
        var total = 0;
        var myroute = result.routes[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
          total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
        }
        total = (total / 1000) * 0.621371;
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
      }
```

```html
function calc_gallons() {
        var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").value)
  var averagempg = parseInt(document.getElementById("averagempg").value);
  var gallons = 0;
  if (averagempg > 0) {
   gallons = total / averagempg
   window.alert("This trip requires " + gallons + " gallon(s). Have safe travels!");
  }else {
   window.alert("Your average MPG must be a positive number in order to calculate the gallons required for this trip.");
  }
      }
```

```html
#this is the text box and the button that does the function
<p>Your Average MPG:<input type="text" id="averagempg" name="MPG"></p>
<button type="button" name="Calculate" onclick="calc_gallons()">Calculate!
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any element with id `averagempg`. Any errors in your console?

Comment: No strangely. And there is no averagempg because I forgot to include that snippet, whoops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is getting `total` inside `calc_gallons()`. You're trying to get it from `value`, but you have it in a `span`. So either put `total` in a disabled input, or get it via innerHTML:

```
var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML);
```

Are you sure you used the console? I failed to see the issue at first, and the following revealed that total is NaN:

```
 console.log("total:", total, typeof total);
 console.log("averagempg:", averagempg, typeof averagempg);
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH YOU ARE AN GENIUS. Yea I'm not very experienced with HTML though.

Comment: You're welcome. And btw you're right, the `.value` doesn't produce an error, it just doesn't return what you need ;)

Answer (score 1):

Better use explicit type conversion:

```
var total = Number(document.getElementById("total").value);
var averagempg = Number(document.getElementById("averagempg").value);
```

`parseInt` then called on empty string ('') returns NaN.

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt
>   returns NaN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Examples: https://coderwall.com/p/kwhkig/javascript-number-conversion

Comment: I replaced those variables, but it still returns NaN

Comment: Heads up for the tip, but the issue was that OP tried to get `.value` from a `span` element  (see OP edit)

Comment: hm. sorry, i've changed the tip